# Wordpress - Frontend file upload and restrict acces by member groups

Tags: wordpress, file, plugins, frontend, upload

Im looking for a plugin or solution that can do this:

Registred user can upload files via fronted. The file should by accessed hierachicaly.

Via diagram -> User B uploads file from website fronted. User A can access this file, but User C cannot see this file.
[image: Diagram Users]

Is there any solution or plugin, could be paid, that can do this?

Thank you for you answers.